# VS2010: How to avoid Windows Forms designer problems when working with inherited user controls?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, designer

Problem: The Windows Forms designer does not work for an inherited user control when the base class is implementing an interface from another assembly.

Platform: VS 2010 SP1, .NET 4.0 Framework

Error:

> The designer could not be shown for
>   this file because none of the classes
>   within it can be designed. The
>   designer inspected the following
>   classes in the file: MyControl --- The
>   base class
>   'MyBaseControlLib.MyBaseControl' could
>   not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has
>   been referenced and that all projects
>   have been built.
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   serializationManager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32
>   fReload)

I have a solution with 3 class library projects:

MyInterfaceLib:

```
namespace MyInterfaceLib
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void Foo();
    }
}
```

MyBaseControlLib:

```
namespace MyBaseControlLib
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using MyInterfaceLib;

    public partial class MyBaseControl : UserControl, IMyInterface
    {
        public MyBaseControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

MyDerivedLib:

```
namespace MyDerivedControlLib
{
    using MyBaseControlLib;

    public partial class MyControl : MyBaseControl
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Although the designer works for MyBaseControl it does not work for MyControl.
If MyBaseControl does not implement IMyInterface, the designer also works for MyControl.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Isn't the key to this in "The base class 'MyBaseControlLib.MyBaseControl' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built."..?

Comment: In my (limited) experience, VS just has a lot of problems with user controls and custom controls that live in the same solution where you are consuming them. I've always had a lot less problems when I just lower my "convenience ambition level" and accept this, and create a separate solution for the controls. Then I just reference the DLL from the other projects and use "rebuid" rather than "build" if I've modified the controls themselves.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue. We used a workarround by creating a MyControlDesign class that is inherited by MyControl class.

```
 public partial class MyControl : MyControlDesign {
   public MyControl()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }
}

public partial class MyControlDesign : MyBaseControl
{
  public MyControlDesign ():base()
  {
  }
}
```