# UltraWinGrid Infragistics gui add column

Tags: c#, ultrawingrid

I have to extend a Infragistics UltraWinGrid View in C# by adding a simple column to an existing grid. However the column is not added after I edit the ColumnDefinition in Properties of the view ( C# Designer ). I see the previous columns there and add a new column, but it doens't show up the Designer, not the application where I test it.

To be more specific, I use the Inherited User Control when I create the extended view in C#.

What I have tried so far:

- Close C# solution, close VS2010. Reopen solution.
- Clean solution, then build.

Comment: I run into this problem all the time and havent found a 100 percent solution yet. First of all, try to just add the column in the designer, save and close the designer - when you run your application, the column might be there (even tho you dont see it in the designer when you reopen it)

Comment: I have done that, and it doens't appear in the application either. I wouldn't mind not seeing it in the designer as long as I would see it in the application...

Comment: Right. Its an inherited user control, correct? The VS designer (as well as the infrag components) dont get along with all that great, there is a trick that often helps, see the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405986/vs2010-how-to-avoid-windows-forms-designer-problems-when-working-with-inherited) question (altough that one is different from yours)

Comment: The problem is I don't get any errors. It compiles, but the column is just not added.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Manually add the column to the spreadsheet, and update the view. The changes will not appear in the Designer, but the new column will be displayed when running the application and displaying the window with the spreadsheet.